# Potential of 2 parallel plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

How can I write down a potential of 2 parallel plates (area $A$) with charge $+Q$, $-Q$ such that V(inf)=0 and V(in) is what I would expect, $Ed = Qd/A\epsilon_0$. Do I have to write a discontinuous potential? If I ignore fringing fields, potential everywhere outside the volume A*d should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Potential is never discontinuous.

Sure, without fringing what you say is correct.  Fringing is what makes the potential continuous in this case.